# Users Not Receiving Push Notifications Just From Me

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have a messaging app and I use Parse server as my backend.

Push notifications work just fine between my users, however whenever I send a message from my user account, the recipient does not get a push notification (even though it looks like it was delivered to APNS just fine). If I log in with another users account on my phone, push notifs are delivered fine, but as soon as I log back into my own account, push notifs are not received by others.

My code is not doing anything different for my user than it is for others. The message is saved to the database just fine (recipients can manually refresh to get my messages on their app - they just don't get the push notif).

It seems like APNS for some reason is not delivering just the push notifs for my user.

Anybody experience anything like this before? Or any ideas how I can debug this?

UPDATE: Cloud function that sends the push

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToUser2", function(request, response) {
    var senderUser = request.user;
    var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
    var message = request.params.message;
    
    if (message.length > 140) {
        message = message.substring(0, 137) + "...";
    }
    
    // Find devices associated with the recipient user
    var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
    recipientUser.id = recipientUserId;
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo("user", recipientUser);
    
    // Send the push notification to results of the query
    Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
            alert: senderUser.get("name"),
            badge: "Increment",
            message: message,
            title: senderUser.get("name"),
            senderObjId: senderUser,
            sound: "sounds.caf",
            "content-available": 1
        }
    }, { success: function() {
        console.log("PUSH SUCCESSFUL");
    }, error: function(error) {
        console.log("PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
    }, useMasterKey: true});
});
```

Comment: Does your user has same roles and permissions that the other users have to the installation class?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, yes same roles and permissions. But how would that even affect whether APNS delivers my users push or not. I'm not very familiar with how Parse communicates with APNS - if there is anything parse might include in the APNS call that would cause APNS to not deliver the push.

Comment: Before sending the APNS call, Parse tries to find out the installations it needs to send to and maybe it was not finding because of permissions issues. Do you have any custom handler on your app? Any beforeFind, afterFind trigger for your Installation class? Are you sending the push from your user only to another user or you are actually sending push to your user as well?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo No custom handler. No beforeIFind or afterFind. I am only sending push to another user, I am not sending the push to myself as well.

Comment: Could you share the code that you are using to send the push?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I've updated my cloud function to be very simple since I've been troubleshooting this. See my edited question for the code.

Comment: The code should work regardless of the user. The only reasons I can imagine it could fail only for your user is if for some reason your user is not logged in. Have you tried to add some console.log() around this code to make sure that all vars are set for your user in the same they are set for the others?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, I did add console logs to look at the vars and everything looks the same as for other users. Nothing is missing from my user. I really think that maybe APNS blocked my user for my app. Could that be possible? I don’t know why they would. My next step is email them and ask.

Comment: APNS does not know which user is sending the push. And the pushes are actually sent from the server and not directly from the device. BTW, why are you sending `senderObjId: senderUser`? Are you using this information in some way in the client side? I thought you had not custom handler on your app. Could you share this part of the code?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, maybe I misunderstood what you meant by custom handler. I'm sending senderObjId because when a push arrives to the recipients phone, certain actions are performed with that userId, and I believe this was the simplest way for me to easily read the userId. I added this years ago, so I'll have to go back and look at exactly what I'm doing with that. But the fact remains that it works fine for other users, just not mine.

I've reached out to Apple Support and they will look into why the push is not being sent (if thats the case). I just need to send them some info about the push.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, APNS asked for the DeviceToken along with datetime and details about the payload of the push so they can track it down. So they should be able to track the push send from my user - I hope. I'll let you know what they say.

Comment: Ok. Let me know then. But I guess that the problem is on the client side, at the moment your code handles the payload.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, you're right the problem is on the client side. Apple said they do not even see the notification come into their APNS. So I started messing with the code, and I removed the senderObjId: senderUser line, that you questioned earlier, and it started working! I don't understand why that line only affects my user, and it only started doing it a couple of weeks ago after years of working fine. I'll just have to update my code on the app to not expect that incoming var, but I would still like to know what the issue was. You should answer with that suggestion so I can award you the bounty

Comment: I am glad you've had some progress on that. If you want to share the code that you have in place for handling the push, I can try to help figuring it out.

Comment: Thanks @DaviMacêdo. The cloud code that handles the push is what I listed in the question above. The problem is the "senderObjId: senderUser". You mentioned in a prior comment above that this is a "custom handler". If I remove this, push are successfully sent by my user. Am I not properly sending that custom handler. I'd like to keep it if possible. What could be the reason that including that will not allow Heroku (thats who I use as my backend) to deliver the push to APNS?

Comment: You probably have a code like the ones in [this link](http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#responding-to-the-payload) in your iOS app, right? That's probably the place you use the `senderObjId` var that you are sending. I guess the problem is over there.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, the senderUser object had a LOT of info in it about the user. That object accumulated a lot of info over the years, and I forgot that I was passing that in the push notif. I think it was too large. My account has more info than most, so thats probably why it affected me. I only needed three items from that object so I modified the call to only send the 3 items rather than the whole senderUser object, and that fixed it. I was probably reaching the size limit in my payload. But thanks for helping me work through this. I really appreciate you talking through this with me.

Comment: I'm glad you've figured it out. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the this object "**senderObjId: senderUser**" that I was passing in the data was very large. It probably exceeded the payload limit. I only really needed 3 items from that object and passed those instead, and it started working. That object kept building up over time without me noticing, and it only affected users who had a lot built up in that object.

Thanks for you help with this @DaviMacêdo.